# Misspelled tag [variable-subsitution] should be renamed

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, spelling

Found a misspelled tag [variable-subsitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-subsitution). (`t` is missing after `subs`).

But it has 55 questions.

This tag has the following stats and has not been corrected for a long time.

> created : 10 years, 8 months ago

I tried to fix one question with this tag. But I got this response.

> Creating the new tag 'variable-substitution' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

Comment: I'll migrate to MSO. They could create the correct tag, and a mod could merge it.Could consider adding a link to the mispelled tag

Comment: I’ve rolled back [revision 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/405971/4) because I’ve added the tag link in the first paragraph already, so it wasn’t necessary to mention it again.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks, this has been corrected. (I've had a bad day, so someone else can chime in with the requisite pun.)

Comment: *"I substituted to the correct name"*?